# Count continuous repeated occurrence of characters from String

Tags: java

This is my code.

```
public static void countContinuosOccurence() {
    String first = "ABBCDDDEFGGH";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < first.length(); i++) {
        if (first.charAt(i) == (first.charAt(i - 1))) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > 1) {

                result.append(String.valueOf(count) + first.charAt(i - 1));
            } else {
                result.append(first.charAt(i - 1));
            }
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("First String is:"+ first);
    System.out.println("Result is:" + result);
}
```

The result is:

```
First String is:ABBCDDDEFGGH
Result is:A2BC3DEF2G
```

It is missing the last character? May someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Is it a fair assumption to make that the string will always have the same characters together in sequence?

Comment: Shouldn't your loop start at 0 instead of 1?

Comment: @danielbeard: No, the loop starting with 1 is fine, as he is taking care of first character by `first.charAt(i - 1)`. Only missing thing is the `count` and *character* of the last run is not appended to `result`.

Comment: His current code would not have printed anything if it was given an input of say "A". I am assuming that danielbeard is trying to nudge the OP to another implementation that goes from 0 to length instead of 1 to length which would pretty much guarantee that he doesn't miss any characters and such.

Comment: @Sanchit: Make sense. But my point was that the current approach can also be modified the way _codaddict_ has done it in his answer.

Comment: The prolem is solved now.Thanks for Supporting me!

Comment: Ok. I just hope you understand the question correctly user1360081.  Cause your code might not give the right answer for say.. "ABABABAB" cause given your question heading.. you might actually want it to print 4A4B or something.

Comment: @Sanchit: i got it.The question heading must be "Count Continuous repeated character from String".I mean "AA"-->"2A","BBB"-->"3B".Thanks again!

Comment: @Sanchit: You are right. But looking at the method name OP has used  i.e. `countContinuosOccurence()` so I think he wanted count of `Continuous occurrence` rather than `Repeated occurrence`. Question title is misleading :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not top-performing, but simplest code:

```
final String in = "ABBCDDDEFGGH" + '\u0000';
final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
char prev = in.charAt(0);
int rpt = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < in.length(); i++) {
  final char curr = in.charAt(i);
  if (curr == prev) rpt++;
  else {
    b.append(rpt == 0? prev : "" + (rpt + 1) + prev);
    rpt = 0; prev = curr;
  }
}
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: Not a big difference, but I made an edit, changing `Character` back to `char`. I needed it before I made this simplification with appending the null-char.

Answer (score 3):

After the `for` loop ends, you'll need to append the *count* and the *character* of the last run of character(s) to the result:

```
public static void countContinuosOccurence() {
    String first = "ABBCDDDEFGGH";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    int count = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < first.length(); i++) {
        if (first.charAt(i) == (first.charAt(i - 1))) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > 1) {    
                result.append(String.valueOf(count) + first.charAt(i - 1));
            } else {
                result.append(first.charAt(i - 1));
            }
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    // ADD THIS - to take care of the last run.
    if (count > 1) {    
        result.append(String.valueOf(count) + first.charAt(i - 1));
    } else {
        result.append(first.charAt(i - 1));
    }

    System.out.println("First String is:"+ first);
    System.out.println("Result is:" + result);
}
```

Comment: +1 because currently you only log when the charcter changes, but at the end this doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void countContinuosOccurence() {

    String[] input = "ABBCDDDEFGGH".split("");
        String out = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            int repeatedCharCount = 1;
            String currentChr = input[i];
            if (!(i == input.length - 1)) {
                while (input[i].equals(input[i + 1])) {
                    repeatedCharCount++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            out = out + repeatedCharCount + currentChr;
        }

        System.out.println(out);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a hidden problem, that is that if you are terminating with a sequence with more than one occurrence, you will not write anything.

The simplest way to solve this problem and the problem you detected is to add a final check after the for block

```
[...]
    }
    int l = first.length();
    if (count > 1) {
        result.append(String.valueOf(count) + first.charAt(l - 1));
        } else {
            result.append(first.charAt(l - 1));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("First String is:"+ first);
    System.out.println("Result is:" + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    String first = "ABBCDDDEFGGHhhhhh456456456{{{67}}}";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
result.append(first);
System.out.println(result);
    Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
char c = first.charAt(i);
if (map.containsKey(c)) {
int cnt = map.get(c);
map.put(c, ++cnt);
} else {
map.put(c, 1);
}

}
Set set = map.entrySet(); 
// Get an iterator 
Iterator itr = set.iterator(); 
// Display elements 
while(itr.hasNext()) { 
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)itr.next(); 
System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": "); 
System.out.println(me.getValue()); 
} 
System.out.println("Hello World1");
 }
}
```